# How to add border along the <td>/<th> tag in Table

Tags: html, css

When i am using the code below I can get Background Color but not the Border along the td tag. Also I am Unable to add the Spacing between two td tags . I tried cellspacing and cellpadding

```css
.bd-highlight {
  margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 10px;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="columntab">
  <div class="col-6" id="columnmain">
    <table class="t1" cellspacing="10">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="bd-highlight"><a href="download/EXTC/SEM3 CBCGS/EIC/SE-EXTC_SEM3_EIC-CBCGS_DEC18.pdf" download="">Dec 2018</a></th>
          <th><a href="download/EXTC/SEM3 CBCGS/EIC/SE-EXTC_SEM3_EIC-CBCGS_MAY18.pdf" download="">May 2018</a></th>
          <th><a href="download/EXTC/SEM3 CBCGS/EIC/SE-EXTC_SEM3_EIC-CBCGS_DEC17.pdf" download="">Dec 2017</a></th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    2 of 3 (wider)
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    3 of 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add ``border: 1px solid;``

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `border:5px(border-width) solid(type) #ff0000(custom-color);`

```
   table tbody tr td,
    table tbody tr th
    {
       margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
       padding-right: 20px;
       border-radius: 25px;
       background: #73AD21;
       padding: 20px;
      width: 135px;
      height: 10px;
      border:5px solid #f00;
    }
```

```css
/*.bd-highlight {
  margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 10px;
  border-color: white;
}*/

table tbody tr td,
table tbody tr th
{
  margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 10px;
  border:5px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="columntab">
  <div class="col-6" id="columnmain">
    <table class="t1" cellspacing="10">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="bd-highlight"><a href="download/EXTC/SEM3 CBCGS/EIC/SE-EXTC_SEM3_EIC-CBCGS_DEC18.pdf" download="">Dec 2018</a></th>
          <th><a href="download/EXTC/SEM3 CBCGS/EIC/SE-EXTC_SEM3_EIC-CBCGS_MAY18.pdf" download="">May 2018</a></th>
          <th><a href="download/EXTC/SEM3 CBCGS/EIC/SE-EXTC_SEM3_EIC-CBCGS_DEC17.pdf" download="">Dec 2017</a></th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    2 of 3 (wider)
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    3 of 3
  </div>
</div>
```